# Reversing a string in MIPS

Tags: mips

Trying to get this program to work but I can't figure out why I keep getting an error. The program is suppose to take an entry of 11 characters, then output the reversed input. The error is as below.

> Runtime exception at 0x00400034: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x7fffeffb

The code is posted below. I also need to store the final reversed string into 'revstr'. I am just having trouble with the reversal.

```
    .data 
str: .space 12
revstr: .space 12
prompt: .asciiz "Enter in string, max 11 characters: "
.text
main:

    la      $a0, prompt     #calling opening prompt
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, str
    li $a1, 12
    syscall

    li $t0, 0
    subu $sp, $sp, 1
    sw $t0, ($sp)
    li $t1, 0

bump1:
    lbu $t0, str($t1)
    beqz $t0, stend
    subu $sp, $sp, 4
    sw $t0, ($sp)
    addu $t1, $t1, 1
    j bump1

stend: li $t1, 0

populate:
    lw $t0, ($sp)
    addu $sp, $sp, 4
    beqz $t0, done
    sb $t0, str($t1)
    addu $t1, $t1, 1
    j populate

done: 
    li $v0, 4
    la $a1, str
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a 32-bit machine, you should use offsets that are multiples of 4 bytes

=> 4*8=32

for you words to be aligned

otherwise your instructions must be byte oriented (lb sb lbu etc.. not lw..)

also correct these:

`lw $t0, ($sp)` it is better to specify the offset to avoid confusion

Comment: Actually, the offset is an implicit `0` in at least my flavour of MIPS assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted confused me pretty good. You are modifying `$sp` in the middle of a function which is generally a no-go, and I couldn't figure out why you were doing it. Also, you say you want to store the reversed string in `revstr` but all `sb` instructions are pointed at `str`.

It's a good idea when communicating assembly to others to give them some pseudo-code to show them the general approach you are attempting to use. Here's mine:

```
str := user_input()
$t1 := len(str)
$t2 := 0
while ($t1 >= 0) {
    revstr[$t2] := str[$t1]
    $t1 := $t1 - 1
    $t2 := $t2 + 1
}
```

With that mental picture, it should be fairly easy to understand how I've modified your assembly:

```
str: .space 12
revstr: .space 12
prompt: .asciiz "Enter in string, max 11 characters: "

.text
main:

    la $a0, prompt     #calling opening prompt
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, str
    li $a1, 12
    syscall

    li $t1, 0

bump1:
    lbu $t0, str($t1)
    beqz $t0, stend
    addu $t1, $t1, 1
    j bump1

stend: 
    li $t2, 0
    addi $t1, $t1 -1

populate:
    blt $t1, $zero, done
    lb $t3, str($t1)
    sb $t3, revstr($t2)
    sub $t1, $t1, 1
    add $t2, $t2, 1
    j populate

done:
    sb $zero, revstr($t2) #null terminate revstr

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, revstr
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```